# Write query which run on array by considring sub query in Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I need to write a query in such way that the array(collection) is contain only sub query objects.

Suppose we have the two tables as follows:

TableA:
objectId, name

TableB:
objectId, names[array of name: parse pointer collection]

Here is my code which I tried:

```
// sub query
var subQuery = new Parse.Query('TableA');
subQuery.doesNotExist('name');

// main query
var query = new Parse.Query('TableB');
query.exists("names");
//query.containsAll("names", subQuery); // this means names should contain all subQuery, so this is not use full for me.
query.matchesQuery("names", subQuery);
```

This code is running fine, but this is not working as I want and also not showing the any error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't need a subquery per se, but rather to first query your list of names, and then use that in your main query.  What you seem to be looking for is: [containedIn( key, values )](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_containedIn) , as in:

```
query.containedIn("name", namesFromFirstQuery)
```